# Can a zookeeper client be made to influence the client-to-server heartbeats?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

In distributed systems that uses Apache Zookeeper for co-ordination, each component is a client to the Zookeeper server, and it instantiates a zookeeper instance, which in the background is sending heartbeats to the zookeeper server. I understand that the time interval for heartbeat communication is configurable. In situations when the "component" itself goes into a "faulty" state but the "heartbeats" to zookeeper is good and unaffected, proper state of this component is not communicated to the rest of the components in the system.

Is it possible out of the box, to influence the heartbeat mechanism - typically by passing a "status reporting function" to the zookeeper instance - to "validate" the status of the component before sending the heartbeat ?